# Does endearingly magically change the connotation of the word it modifies?

Tags: word-request, connotations

> a dad's joke is endearingly corny and unfunny.

Does endearingly magically change the connotation of the word it modifies from negative to positive?

What are other magic adverbs and adjectives that can change the connotation of the words that they modify?

Thanks.

Comment: Some of my family say that my mother's dog is endearingly stupid, but I still won't have it in my house. Just about any 'positive' adverb can, in theory, affect a following negative adjective, e.g. some people are attractively ugly, and some films and books are amusingly dumb. The important thing to remember is that such utterances are _expressions of opinion_.

Comment: Also I thought they were 'dad jokes'.

Comment: No, I wouldn't say so. The jokes are still corny, but you feel more tolerant towards them because it's your dad who is making them.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey why dad not dad's?

Comment: Tim - see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dad_joke - I didn't invent the phrase; don't blame me!

Comment: I can't open Wikipedia, till someone helps me climb over GFW.

Comment: 'Dad joke' is an idiomatic phrase. Says Wikipedia: 'While the exact origin of the term dad joke is unknown, the term was first published by Jim Kalbaugh, who wrote an impassioned defense of the genre in The Gettysburg Times in June 1987 under the headline "Don't ban the 'Dad' jokes; preserve and revere them". ' So it started with quote marks around 'Dad', but as so often happens, once the novelty wore off, and a critical mass of people were using the phrase, the quotes vanished.